# Meaning of "plug fill" or "fill plug" in pharmaceutical industry

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, terminology

From [an FDA guideline](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/Drugs/.../Guidances/ucm073379.pdf):

> Bracketing can be applied to studies with multiple strengths of identical or closely related formulations. Examples include but are not limited to (1) capsules of different strengths made with different **fill plug** sizes from the same powder blend, (2) tablets of different strengths manufactured by compressing varying amounts of the same granulation, and (3) oral solutions of different strengths with formulations that differ only in minor excipients (e.g., colorants, flavorings).

From [a European guideline](http://www.ema.europa.eu/docs/en_GB/document_library/Scientific_guideline/2014/02/WC500162136.pdf):

> Where a range of strengths is to be validated, bracketing could be applicable if the strengths are identical or very closely related in composition (e.g., for a tablet range made with different compression weights of a similar basic granulation, or a capsule range made by filling different **plug fill** weights of the same basic composition into different size capsule shells).

I don't understand the meaning of "plug fill/fill plug" in these texts.

"Plug for filling"? What could that mean?

Comment: This document describes the process of filling a capsule. It explains how a plug of powder is formed and sized when filling the capsule. https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=VAmbWj9aK_oC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA125&dq=plug+fill+capsule&source=bl&ots=e4e6TmjQ4o&sig=-saBtyPG1x-1I-iQ4Yu_wb1hKtA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRh7nh9dvOAhWBfhoKHSbCBegQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=plug%20fill%20capsule&f=false

Comment: @JavaLatte - thank you, but the page is invisible to me ("limit reached"). I'll try to find some similar text by googling for "plug of powder"

Comment: I looked for "plug fill capsule". This might get you the next page, which is the interesting one: https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=VAmbWj9aK_oC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=plug+fill+capsule&source=bl&ots=e4e6TmjQ4o&sig=-saBtyPG1x-1I-iQ4Yu_wb1hKtA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=plug%20fill%20capsule&f=false. You can manually edit pg= and lpg= parameters in the URL to see other parts of the document.

Comment: The "plug" is the compressed material put inside the capsule. Hence it is called the "fill plug": the plug that fills...  With "plug fill weights", **fill** modifies **weights**: the fill weight of the plug.

Comment: Compare **weight**, the lead (Pb) "sinker" attached to a fishing line.A weight is not only a measure but a thing of weight, a thing having weight.

Answer (score 1):

From a combination of the comments and some judicious googling:

A ***fill plug*** is compressed mass of medication in powder or granule form, used to fill *capsules* of medicine. ***Plug fill*** appears to be an alternate term for the same thing.

A *plug* is an object that is stuck into an opening, and that *fills* it. The fill plug is pushed into one side of a capsule before the capsule is sealed.